# In Dark Souls 2, what happens if you kill or don't kill the Pursuer during the first encounter?

Tags: dark-souls-2

**POSSIBLE SPOILER**

What happens if you kill the Pursuer during your first encounter (*the part where a big, armored, shield and greatsword wielding enemy is dropped by a big black bird on a square platform accessed via a ladder*)? What happens if you don't kill him in your first encounter?

If you were unable to kill him during the first encounter, is it possible to gain the first encounter kill rewards in some other way later on in the game (vice versa)?

Please flag your answers for possible spoilers (if any).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***What happens if you kill the Pursuer during your first encounter?***

First of all, that is your only chance to kill him there. If you kill him then that counts as the kill of the boss and he WILL NOT appear at the top of the castle.

***What happens if you don't kill him in your first encounter?***

He will not appear again in that area and you will have to face him at the top of the castle.

***If you were unable to kill him during the first encounter, is it possible to gain the first encounter kill rewards in some other way later on in the game (vice versa)?***

As far as I know, he drops the exact same loot as if you faced him as a regular boss.

***I mention his drops in the next lines, so I guess it counts as a spoiler.***

> He drops Soul of the Pursuer and The Ring of Blades whether you kill him as a 
>  regular boss or when he is dropped by the eagle.